# How to disable unselected option when one of option in optgroup is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2, optgroup

I have form group which is there are 3 select form : Merchant, Order Status, and Order Payment Status. Focus on Merchant selection. I have select option like this.

```
<select id="merchant_uuid" name="merchant_uuid" class="form-control" data-plugin-selectTwo>
    <option value="">All</option>
    <optgroup label="Brands">
    <?php
        if (isset($merchants)) {
           foreach ($merchants as $merchant) {
                echo '<option value='.$merchant['merchant_uuid'].'>'.$merchant['merchant_name'].'</option>';
           }
        }
    ?>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

My expectation when I click option All then option that optgroup as parent is disabled and keep enabled optgroup in other selects.

```
$('merchant_uuid').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        $('optgroup option').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('optgroup option').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

The sample code above still wrong, when I clicked All then all option optgroup was disabled in all form group. Anyone can help me please.

Comment: Your expectation is incorrect. The `option optgroup` selector refers to all option elements that are part of an optgroup, which is exactly the group that is getting disabled. Besides that, you say that your `All` option has something to do with an optgroup, but in your code that option element isn't in an optgroup.

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript code following errors are found...

1. The selector used with element `ID` should start from `#`.
2. For fetch, the option if select element there a proper DOM position is track ie `children() or chain selector`.

check the following may this work for you.

```
$('#merchant_uuid').on('change', function() {

    if (this.value == '') {
        $('#merchant_uuid optgroup option').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#merchant_uuid optgroup option:selected').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#merchant_uuid optgroup option').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

> **Note:** if you don't want to enable the currently selected option then
>   you can remove the second line of if statement.